# Oracle APEX 19.2 character encoding in app builder problem

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, oracle-apex

I have a problem with encoding in ORACLE APEX app builder.
When I'm using a app builder and creating for example a list with entry with polish native chars for example "Otwórz". When i save it it appears on list as "OtwA3rz". So I'm thinking about problem with encoding, but when i use "Grid Edit" on list I can easily use "Otwórz" and save it properly. After that there is a problem with edit this entry in form. Additionally when I create a form with for example textarea in my app there is no problem to save a value with polish chars. There is only a problem with app builder.

Some info from "About Application Express" modul:

> • Product Build   19.2.0.00.18
>
> • Schema Compatibility    2019.10.04
>
> • Last DDL Time   02/05/2020 01:09:01 PM
>
> • Host Schema APEX_PUBLIC_USER
>
> • Application Owner   APEX_190200
>
> • Language Preference en
>
> • Current Time (on server)    03/16/2020 02:17:08 PM +01:00
>
> • APEX_LISTENER_VERSION   19.2.0.r1991647
>
> • PLSQL_GATEWAY   WebDb
>
> • GATEWAY_IVERSION    3
>
> • SERVER_SOFTWARE Mod-Apex
>
> • GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
>
> • REQUEST_METHOD  GET
>
> • QUERY_STRING    p=4350:9:956788024708&p_dialog_cs=e6pVbBxXQReCPpEOwNEhrbAjoGPeY7nX6VVuLL8ObTSnXKlihOrJCOR8f1EU9isYxMT5Ooqgb-j9A33Mmx1aKA
>
> • PATH_INFO   /f
>
> • HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121
>   Safari/537.36
>
> • HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate, br
>
> • HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
>
> • REQUEST_CHARSET AL32UTF8
>
> • REQUEST_IANA_CHARSET    UTF-8    •  Oracle Database 12c Enterprise
>   Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
>
> • CORE    12.2.0.1.0  Production
>
> • NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
>
> • PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
>
> • TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
>
> • NLS_CHARACTERSET:   EE8MSWIN1250
>
> • DAD CHARACTERSET:   UTF-8
>
> • JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES:    15

I noticed that when I run a sql `select 'ó' from dual` the result is exactly 'A3'. I run another `select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS;` and maybe find a reason of all of this. NLS_LANGUAGE is AMERICAN. How to change it for POLISH like I have normally database session configured. When I create my own app with globalization setting there is no problem with setting nls_language to Polish. But i don't know how to change it for app builder

I made a additional experiment i run insert into table value 'ł' and select * from v$nls_parameters thru sql_workshop and sql_script: and below are results:
(syntax parameter:value:method(script or sqlworkshop))

```
NLS_CALENDAR:GREGORIAN:script
NLS_CALENDAR:GREGORIAN:sqlworkshop
NLS_CHARACTERSET:EE8MSWIN1250:script
NLS_CHARACTERSET:EE8MSWIN1250:sqlworkshop
NLS_COMP:BINARY:script
NLS_COMP:BINARY:sqlworkshop
NLS_CURRENCY:$:script
NLS_CURRENCY:$:sqlworkshop
NLS_DATE_FORMAT:mm/dd/yyyy:script
NLS_DATE_FORMAT:mm/dd/yyyy:sqlworkshop
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE:AMERICAN:script
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE:AMERICAN:sqlworkshop
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY:$:script
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY:$:sqlworkshop
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY:AMERICA:script
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY:AMERICA:sqlworkshop
NLS_LANGUAGE:AMERICAN:script
NLS_LANGUAGE:AMERICAN:sqlworkshop
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS:BYTE:script
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS:BYTE:sqlworkshop
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET:AL16UTF16:script
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET:AL16UTF16:sqlworkshop
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP:FALSE:script
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP:FALSE:sqlworkshop
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS:.,:script
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS:.,:sqlworkshop
NLS_SORT:BINARY:script
NLS_SORT:BINARY:sqlworkshop
NLS_TERRITORY:AMERICA:script
NLS_TERRITORY:AMERICA:sqlworkshop
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT:DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM:script
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT:DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM:sqlworkshop
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT:DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR:script
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT:DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR:sqlworkshop
NLS_TIME_FORMAT:HH.MI.SSXFF AM:script
NLS_TIME_FORMAT:HH.MI.SSXFF AM:sqlworkshop
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT:HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR:script
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT:HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR:sqlworkshop
value:A?:sqlworkshop
value:ł:cript
```

and basically they are the same

next thing i did is running with the same method as previously code for inserting userenv parameter, and below are the differences:

```
ACTION::script
ACTION:Processes - point: BEFORE_BOX_BODY:sqlworkshop
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER:::script
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER:#MY_LOGIN#:12101284695326:sqlworkshop
CLIENT_INFO:100001:#MY_LOGIN#:sqlworkshop
CLIENT_INFO:#MY_LOGIN#:script
MODULE:APEX_190200/APEX:APP 4500:1200:sqlworkshop
MODULE:HTML DB:SQL Workshop:Script:test2:script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run APEX on tomcat/ords. I'm using CAS for authentication and I found that implementing CAS (confguring it in xml making these problems). I don't know why and i don't know how, but it appears that this questions is closed, becouse it's a problem with TOMCAT/APEX/ORDS/CAS combine, so I will create new question.

[Encoding problem with APEX app builder caused by CAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830692/encoding-problem-with-apex-app-builder-caused-by-cas)